# Compiled coffeescript preview side by side

Tags: webstorm

Is there a way to see generated javascript all the time?

Of course there's a 'Preview compiled coffescript' command that will open modal window.
not exactly the thing I'm looking for.

Also you always can split window vertically and have both .coffee and .js opened. But then, it won't change automatically when you navigate to a different coffeescript file.

And I'm hoping to have a side panel that maybe supports source maps too.

Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can file a feature request here:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard#newissue=yes

It might be useful for other languages too: TypeScript, Less, Sass, etc

Comment: I'm pretty sure someone already submitted something like it, but I searched and couldn't find any. So I submited a new one:  http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8051

Comment: btw. John, your AceJump is phenomenal! Why no one has implemented that in every single editor (VIM, Sublime, Visual Studio etc.)? It should be the essential feature, like I don't know intellisense or something